# "splitted up" or "split up"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Are there, between these two forms, different meanings ?

- They are split up into small pieces.
- They are splitted up into small pieces.

If they are the same, which is more common ?

**EDIT** - Google ngram for "splitted up":
https://goo.gl/hsftzC

Comment: I can imagine children might say "splitted up". It doesn't really sound wrong to me, even though it is. You should add some usage examples to your question. I wouldn't rely on an ngram alone since there is no context at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb "split" is fully conjugated as shown [here](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-split.html).
There's no form "splitted." So only your first suggestion is grammatical.

(By the way, it seems to me that you could also omit the word "up," and say "split" instead of "split up." But maybe the context would prove me wrong about that.)

Comment: There are many contexts where "split up" is the standard expression, even though the "up" is technically unnecessary.

Comment: I found the use of "splitted up" in google, especially in google ngram: https://goo.gl/hsftzC

Comment: @Luciano *[Split up](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=split+up%2C+splitted+up&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)* is vastly more common. If you look at the actual sample text for *splitted up*, you will not find many high-quality sources; one example is from the book *Varna, Castes, and Scheduled Castes*, and the very paragraph where it appears contains other grammatical errors and unusual usages which mark it as the writing of a non-native speaker or a translation.